# Searching for a value in a two-dimensional python array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to make a project I have to use a two-dimensional table, in this table I have to find precise values. In this short code I try to find the value 6 but I can't.
Thank you in advance for your help

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from math import *
import sys
bord = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


def main():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    while(x < 2):
        while(y < 3):
            print(bord[x][y])
            if (bord[x][y] == 5):
                print("here")
            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
main()
```

Comment: I think that might be because you're searching for 5, not 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in two dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637996/search-in-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: No i want find the number 5 and when i look the value of x in the second while is 0 all time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code that you have to init y not out the loops

```
bord = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]  

def main():
    x = 0

    while(x < 2):
        y = 0
        while(y < 3):
            if (bord[x][y] == 5):
                print("here")
            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
main()
```

Now you loop only the first inner list

Comment: I i don't init y in the top of the function An error is displayed and the program cannot be executed.

Comment: @Malcom.Z place it right under `while (x<2)`. I don't see why that shouldn't work. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_pos(bord, number):
  for list_num in enumerate(bord):
    if number in list_num[1]:
      return (list_num[0], list_num[1].index(number))
```

If you are looking for `6` then this function should return `(1, 2)` which means that your number is in the list with index `1` and at the position with index `1`.

Comment: The question is why it doesn't work with the while?

Comment: @Malcom.Z It was not specified anywhere, I will look into it.